# How do I limit a class that implements an event handler interface to one instance with initializiation parameters?

Tags: swing, singleton, design-patterns, actionlistener

I'm writing a Swing application with login functionality and need to create a
class for the login button that implements the `ActionListener` interface.

This class needs handles to user input fields and GUI controls, and I want to
pass these handles either to the constructor or an initialization method.
(These handles cannot be passed to the `actionPerformed()` event declared in the
interface.) At the same time, only one instance of this class should be
created.

Please suggest the best design options.  I read that the Singleton pattern is
considered flawed, especially when parameters are involved.

Comment: An anonymous class. Only one instance can be created, and when created at the correct location it will have access to those UI components. I dare not say this is the best design, but hey, it tackles 2 of the 3 questions ...

Comment: @Robin, great suggestion!  I can declare a variable of type ActionListener and assign it to the anonymous class.  Thanks!